# Is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

[What subdivision algorithm advances have occurred since Catmull-Clark?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-subdivision-algorithm-advances-have-occurred-since-catmull-clark) asks for the improvements made over the past 37 years.  Since [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivision_surface) lists a number of different improvements over the intervening time, and branching into several different types (approximating/interpolating, quads/triangles), I suspect this question may be too broad to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: Bonus question: would it be less broad if it was phrased "What is the state of the art in subdivision algorithms?" instead? Because that wouldn't cover 37 years, right? (I may or may not be playing the devil's advocate here. ;))

Comment: @MartinBüttner That would certainly make it narrower. It still sounds broad but whether *too* broad I guess could be a separate meta question...

Comment: I guess another way of phrasing this is "do we want a history tag?"